# Adding multiple prefixes discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, prefix

I want to implement custom prefixes per server as, well as a permanent prefix which is bot mention, which means people can use like default prefix `.` as well as `@bot` and the prefixes are stored in json file.

Here is my current code:

```py
with open("prefixes.json") as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)
default_prefix = "."

def get_prefix(client, message): 
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f: 
        prefixes = json.load(f) 
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] 

client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix= (get_prefix),
    intents=intents
    )


@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild): 
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f: 
        prefixes = json.load(f) 

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '.'

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f: 
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4) 

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild): 
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id)) 

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f: 
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) 
async def prefix(ctx, prefix): 
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f: 
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'`Prefix changed to:` {prefix}')
```

I tried to find a way and tried the way below and it threw errors. Any help will be appreciated.

```py
client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix= [(get_prefix), '<@!123>'],
    intents=intents
    )
```

json file format:

```
{
    "121212121212121221": "-",
    "121212121212121222": "-",
    "121212121212121223": "!",
    "121212121212121224": "-",
    "121212121212121225": "."
}
```

Comment: thanks @Diggy. I am a bit weak in english! Thanks for correcting my mistakes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an improved version

```py
def get_prefix(client, message):
    prefix = default_prefix 
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f: 
        prefixes = json.load(f) 
        prefix = prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] 

    return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(client, message)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
```

Comment: thanks very much bro this thing help me very much a saved a lot of time for me...i was trying it since 2 hours but found no solution...but this worked...thanks very much